# want to display image into tableview cell from an api with only image name

Tags: ios, swift, image, api

I have an API in which only `image_name` is given. How do I load an image into a `UITableViewCell`. I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for it. I am getting `hotal_originalname` and `hotal_address` but no image. I have tried but not getting it.

The Code I have tried so far:

**hotelModel struct:**

```
struct hotelModel {
    var hotal_originalname:String = ""
    var hotal_image:String = ""
    var hotal_address:String = ""

    init(json:JSON) {
        hotal_originalname = json["hotal_originalname"].stringValue
        hotal_image = json["hotal_image"].stringValue
        hotal_address = json["hotal_address"].stringValue
    }
}
```

**Code with Alamofire code:**

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController{

    let BASE_URL = "https://socialinfotech.in/development/ExcelReport/api/v1/hotel"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "X-Authorization": "2933c869ebe0a3e42a068ec50e305db5",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    var arrData = [hotelModel]()

    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var listViewTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set gradient to navigation bar
        SHNDNavigationBarGradient(firstColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.3450980392, green: 0.737254902, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1), secondColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.262745098, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.7921568627, alpha: 1))
        jsonParsing()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    func jsonParsing() {

        Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response)-> Void in
          debugPrint(response)

            if(response.result.value) != nil {
                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                let results = json["Result"]
                for arr in results.arrayValue {
                    self.arrData.append(hotelModel(json: arr))
                    print(self.arrData)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.listViewTable.reloadData()
                }
            }


        }

    }

    //MARK: IBActions
    @IBAction func logoutBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN")
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }
}

extension ListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell

        let imgUrl = "http://socialinfotech.in/development/ExcelReport/uploads/original/"
        let url = imgUrl + "uploads-35766-1557402138-20190509-114218am.jpg"


        cell.hotelImage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: url))
        cell.hotelName.text = arrData[indexPath.row].hotal_originalname
        cell.hotelAddress.text = arrData[indexPath.row].hotal_address
//
//        Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { (response) in
//            if let image = response.result.value {
//                cell.hotelImage.image = image
//            }
//        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let chartVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChartViewController") as! ChartViewController
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chartVC, animated:true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting only image name ?. is it part of image url ? if yes then you can append string into your `imgUrl` var just like you add static string **uploads-35766-1557402138-20190509-114218am.jpg**

Comment: yes its part of image url

Comment: Then just replace this line **imgUrl + "uploads-35766-1557402138-20190509-114218am.jpg"**

  this with  `let url = imgUrl + arrData[indexPath.row]. hotal_image`

Comment: ok...its done thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using static image url.

Replace this line

```
    let imgUrl = "http://socialinfotech.in/development/ExcelReport/uploads/original/"
    let url = imgUrl + "uploads-35766-1557402138-20190509-114218am.jpg"
```

with

```
    let imgUrl = "http://socialinfotech.in/development/ExcelReport/uploads/original/"
    let url = imgUrl + arrData[indexPath.row].hotal_image
```

Hope it is helpful